# How to call an instance class method from a static method with reflection

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

```
namespace ClassLibraryB {
    public class Class1 {
        public void Add(int ii, int jj)
        {
            i = ii;
            j = jj;
            result = i + j;
        }
        public void Add2()
        {
            result =  i + j;
        }
    }
}
```

This gets called statically and gives me an answer

```
ClassLibraryB.Class1 objB = new ClassLibraryB.Class1();
objB.Add(4, 16);
objB.Add2();
kk = objB.result;
textBox1.Text += "Addition =" + kk.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

However when I try to call the dll using below it fails with since it is not static

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(strDLL);
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("ClassLibraryB.Class1");
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("i");
numberPropertyInfo.SetValue(calcInstance, 5, null);
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo2 = calcType.GetProperty("j");
numberPropertyInfo2.SetValue(calcInstance, 15, null);
int value2 = (int)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);
int value3 = (int)numberPropertyInfo2.GetValue(calcInstance, null);
calcType.InvokeMember("Add2",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
    null, null, null);
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo3 = calcType.GetProperty("result");
int value4 = (int)numberPropertyInfo3.GetValue(calcInstance, null);
```

I just need to know exactly what changes I have to make to the dll class to be able to call it here

Comment: Any specific reason why you are loading it with reflection, instead of just referencing it?

Comment: Not really. I m just trying to find an example to be able to call a dll function pass some parameters and get a simple value back that's all  in c#

Comment: There is no `result` declared.

Comment: Bit is failing when Add2 being called

Comment: Non-static method requires a target.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass an instance of the type to `InvokeMember`

```
calcType.InvokeMember("Add2", flags, null, calcInstance, null);
```

---

If you are creating a plug-in, the right thing to do is to have three assemblies.

1. A class library (dll) containing an interface declaration of the plug-in
2. A class library (dll) containing an implementation of the interface (the plug-in)
3. An executable (exe) loading the plug-in

The interface DLL is referenced by the two other components. You need three assemblies because the plug-in should not know anything about your application and the application should not know anything about your plug-in other than its interface. This makes the plug-ins interchangeable and different applications can use the same plug-in.

---

Interface Assembly `Calculator.Contracts.dll`

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

---

Plug-in implementation `Calculator.dll`

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

---

Now you can load the plug-in and use it in a typed way in the application (exe):

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(strDLL);
string calcInterfaceName = typeof(ICalculator).FullName;
foreach (Type type in asm.GetExportedTypes()) {
    Type interfaceType = type.GetInterface(calcInterfaceName);
    if (interfaceType != null &&
        (type.Attributes & TypeAttributes.Abstract) != TypeAttributes.Abstract) {

        ICalculator calculator = (ICalculator)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        int result = calculator.Add(2, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: The interface goes in its own DLL (class library) directly inside the namespace. This DLL does not contain anything else. You could call this Assembly `Calculator.Contracts.dll`.

Comment: Its All good Olivier . Some project dependencies issue but now sorted out , so thanks a lot for your help mate